# "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed" when migrating in rails 6 with multiple database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Rails 6.0.2.1 with multiple database.

I wrote a migration to add references to a table and **set the default using a query**.
When Running the migration i am encountering an error and i am not able to understand the reason for the error.

Also, I am not using any gem like octopus etc for multiple db management

Migration File

```
class AddServiceToTinkLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    TinkLog.connection.add_reference :tink_logs, :service, null: false, index: true, default: Service.find_by_name("tink").id
  end
end
```

Another Migration for the same task,without using Connection method

```
class AddServiceToTinkLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :tink_logs, :service, null: false, foreign_key: true, default: Service.find_by_name('tink').id
  end
end
```

Both the migration are working and run successfully,the changes are also reflected in the database.But still the following error is shown after the migrations are executed

```
== 20210316124201 AddServiceToTinkLogs: migrating =============================
== 20210316124201 AddServiceToTinkLogs: migrated (0.3611s) ====================

rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `exec'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:64:in `block in query'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:718:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:717:in `block in log'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:708:in `log'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `query'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:98:in `query_value'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:383:in `release_advisory_lock'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1384:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1229:in `migrate'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `up'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `migrate'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `exec'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:64:in `block in query'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:718:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:717:in `block in log'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:708:in `log'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `query'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:98:in `query_value'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:383:in `release_advisory_lock'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1384:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1229:in `migrate'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `up'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `migrate'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/bhavesh1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@external_api/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The migration here is successfull, and the changes are also made.

Any help is deeply appreciated.